# Create word document and then attach it to email Django

Tags: python, django, email, python-docx

I'm currently using python_docx in order to create Word Documents in Python. What I'm trying to achieve is that I need to create Document File in Django and then attach it to an email using django.core.mail without having to save the file on the server. I've tried creating the Word File using this (taken from an answer also within StackOverflow):

```
def generate(self, title, content):
    document = Document()
    docx_title=title
    document.add_paragraph(content)

    f = BytesIO()
    document.save(f)
    length = f.tell()
    f.seek(0)
    response = HttpResponse(
        f.getvalue(),
        content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
    )
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + docx_title
    response['Content-Length'] = length
    return response
```

And then here is where I experimented and tried to attach the response to the email:

```
def sendmail(self, name,email,description,location):
    message = EmailMessage('Custom Mail', 'Name: '+str(name)+'\nEmail: '+str(email)+'\nDescription: '+str(description)+'\nLocation: '+str(location), 'test@gmail.com',to=['testreceiver@gmail.com'])
    docattachment = generate('Test','CONTENT')
    message.attach(docattachment.name,docattachment.read(),docattachment.content_type)
    message.send()
```

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?

**EDIT:** I based the code of message.attach() from the parameters of the attach() function in django.core.mail

Comment: Sure this is possible. However, I don't see the need to make a `HTTPResponse` object. Are you getting any errors with this?

Comment: Yeah. A lot, is there a shorter or different way to do this?

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Can you add the errors to your question

Comment: They basically say that the attributes name and read are not defined for an HttpResponse object

Comment: The answer to your second question, What you are trying to achieve is entirely possible. You just need to correct your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this code :

```
def sendmail(self, name,email,description,location):
    message = EmailMessage('Custom Mail', 'Name: '+str(name)+'\nEmail: '+str(email)+'\nDescription: '+str(description)+'\nLocation: '+str(location), 'test@gmail.com',to=['testreceiver@gmail.com'])
    docattachment = generate('Test','CONTENT')
    message.attach(docattachment.name,docattachment.read(),docattachment.content_type)
    message.send()
```

In this line :

```
message.attach(docattachment.name,docattachment.read(),docattachment.content_type)
```

**docattachment** is the response got from generate() fucntion, and **docattachment** does not have any attribute named : name or read()

You need to replace above code with this:

```
message.attach("Test.doc",docattachment,'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
```

And the making of the file, it shouldn't be an HttpResponse and instead use **BytesIO** to deliver the file.

Comment: Well, it wasn't exactly your answer that made it work, but it did help me figuring out how. Thanks.

Comment: I'm honestly at a loss if I should since there are other factors as to why your answer wouldn't work as is since you should've pointed out the it shouldn't be an HttpResponse and instead use BytesIO. I'm giving it an upvote but if you edit it, yeah. I'll accept it :)