# Create a document using python-docx and send as attachment through django

Tags: python, django, email, email-attachments, python-docx

I have created a document using docx and tried to send as an email attachment without saving the document on the server. Below is my code:

```
Document = document()
paragraph = document.add_paragraph("Test Content")
f = BytesIO()
document.save(f)
file_list = []
file_list.append(["Test.docx",f, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"]
email = EmailMessage(subject = 'Test', body = 'Hi', to = ['test@test.com'], attachments = file_list)
email.send()
```

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not BytesIO

on the line `email.send()`

I tried converting BytesIO to StringIO as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566630/convert-io-bytesio-to-io-stringio-to-parse-html-page)

```
f = f.read()
f = StringIO(f.decode('UTF-8'))
```

and then I get the error:

> TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not StringIO

I looked at the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215083/create-word-document-and-then-attach-it-to-email-django), but didn't understand how the `document` is sent as an attachment.

Any help or pointers is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was in the error message.

Instead of

```
file_list.append(["Test.docx",f, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"]
```

I did

```
file_list.append(["Test.docx", f.getValue(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"]
```

Because in my code `f` is a `BytesIO` object and `f.getValue()` returns the contents of the object as `bytes`.

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO.getvalue